# Autocomplete text in contentEditable div

Tags: javascript, html, caret

I need a sort of autocomplete mechanism on a contentEditable div. So when typing "s", it will be changed into "Set " after a pop-up selection (pretty much like Intellisense in VS works), so I need two things:

1. Remove the original typed string (I'm keeping track of this separately)
2. Inserting the new text at this certain position

I think this will be easy if I could get the caret position within the div innerHTML, so that I can conduct the text logic and then set back the html into the div. But I haven't found how to achieve this so far.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you'll need to be using text selection functionality, but this tends to have fairly poor cross browser compatibility and can be very frustrating to use. It would  be worth looking into using a library such as Rangy (https://code.google.com/p/rangy/) to standardise this.

The documentation there should also give a good starting point for finding out how to select the text around the cursor, and perform replacements of the text content of a selection.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/yuku-t/jquery-textcomplete/ works with contentEditable and lets you run a hook on finding a match.